# Issue with setColorFilter

Tags: java, android

if i click on "favorite" the heart became red this is the code:

```
holder.preferiti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    onImageClickListener.onPreferitiClick2(video2.getPic(), video.getTitolo(), video.getSottotitolo(), video.getData(), iddd);
                    // holder.preferiti.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.preferiti.setColorFilter(Color.RED);

                    System.out.println("dentro adapter 2:" + video2.getPic() + video.getTitolo() + video.getSottotitolo() + video.getData() + iddd);

            }

        });
```

but if i click again on favorite i what change color of holder.preferiti object....How can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: try with two drawable images. change background with the red image.

Comment: Screenshot to understand better

Comment: add it in else statement

Comment: @oliver try my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use toggle button instead like this with 2 different drawable.

```
   toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp);

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Toggle Button Else of If Calling");
                toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_white_24dp);


            }
        }
        });
```

Comment: with toggle button interface onImageClickListener.onPreferitiClick2(video2.getPic(), video.getTitolo(), video.getSottotitolo(), video.getData(), iddd); is not called, why?

Comment: Replace your view with toggle button. You can easily achieve your task easily with toggle button. Dont use any other onClickListener thn toggle one